# (database first) uniqueidentifier and MVC = duplicate key value

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created an user table in Sql server Management that include primary key **Id**(`uniqueidentifier`), Name and so on.. I used Entity Framework(database first) to access my database. Everything looked good and I could list data(if I had any).

I created a controller/view for a "Create" page to add new user. Creating a user for the first time worked well, but I couldn't add any more since I got this following order:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_User'. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'dbo.User'. The duplicate key value is
>   (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000). The statement has been
>   terminated.

As I understand, uniqueidentifier should generate a new and unique guid id every time. This following code is basically just what I wrote, and simply added View.

```
   public class UserController : Controller {

    UserEntities db = new UserEntities();

    public ActionResult Index() {

        return View(db.Users.ToList());
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(User user) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

This is auto generated code(database first)

```
namespace User
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class User
    {
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you provide the html code for the view?

Comment: it's to long to add, but the view is auto-generated by adding View -> and pick "Create" as Template. Just like this tutorial in 14:05 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0Xs33UMLnA). It has nothing to do with `Id` as far I understand.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are inserting another user with the same ID. You can do one of the following:

You can use a constraint in your model. Doing so your ModelState won't be valid and the data won't be stored.

You can also check the values you are sending via POST from your form in order to see if you are sending an Id value from the form.

Another possible solution can be trying to auto-increment the primary key value.
Try adding this to your model:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid guId { get; set; }
```

UPDATED:
Another possible solution:

1. Open your edmx file.
2. Right click -> Model Browser
3. Right click the Guid column -> Properties -> change the
   StoreGeneratedPattern to Identity.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Where do I auto-increment, and also check values via POST as you mentioned? I'm new to MVC, hope you don't mind.

Comment: To check the values you can debug your app and check the values of the user object. To create a autoincremente: I edited the answer and added the code you should add to your model.

Comment: The updated solution worked as well which I prefer more. Thanks again.